# How to Update the final value if user enters new Value with Android TextWatcher

Tags: android, android-edittext, user-input, textwatcher

As I'm very new to android I just try to learn things. So excuse me if I 'm asking silly questions.
This is how my android app looks like.

I add a new edittext field where user can add a value like(e.g. 3%), if he likes. Then user entered value(e.g.3%) should calculate with the total value in the Result TextView and that value needs to display in the Sub Value textview field. For example if the total value in the Final Result textview is 1000 and user input 3%, then Sub Value field displays 30. And then Final Result needs to update to 1030. Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance

[image]

```
public class AddTwo extends AppCompatActivity {

        EditText edit1, edit2, edit3;
        EditText edit4, edit5, edit6;



        TextView textViewSub1, textViewSub2, textViewSub3, textViewSub4, textViewResult;
        TextView nbtText;

        EditText editNbt, vat;

        Button btnNext;

        /**
         * Called when the activity is first created.
         */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_two);

            btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

            btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    gotoNextPage();
                }

                private void gotoNextPage() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(AddTwo.this, NewClass.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

        /*Vat variables*/
            editNbt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edittext11);


        /*First row variables*/
            edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            edit3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            textViewSub1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewsub1);

        /*Second row variables*/
            edit4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
            edit5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
            edit6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
            textViewSub2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewsub2);

        /*Final Total TextView variable*/
            textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_result);

        /*NBT value variable*/
            nbtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNbt12);

            edit1.addTextChangedListener(new LashCustomTextWatcher());
            edit2.addTextChangedListener(new LashCustomTextWatcher());
            edit3.addTextChangedListener(new LashCustomTextWatcher());
            edit4.addTextChangedListener(new LashCustomTextWatcher());
            edit5.addTextChangedListener(new LashCustomTextWatcher());
            edit6.addTextChangedListener(new LashCustomTextWatcher());
            textViewResult.addTextChangedListener(new LashCustomTextWatcher());
        }

        public class LashCustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                textViewResult.setText(lashCalculate());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                textViewResult.setText(lashCalculate());
            }
        }

        public String lashCalculate() {
            //declaring variables
            double row1_value = 0;
            double row2_value = 0;


            //Optional Values
            double row_nbt_value = 0;
            double row1_value_new = 0;

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");

            //calculate first row
            if (!edit1.getText().toString().equals("") && !edit2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                double num1 = Double.parseDouble((edit1.getText().toString()));
                double num2 = Double.parseDouble((edit2.getText().toString()));

                row1_value = num1 * num2;

                double num3 = 0;
                if (!edit3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    num3 = Double.parseDouble((edit3.getText().toString()));
                    row1_value = (((100 - num3) * num2) * num1) / 100;
                }

                textViewSub1.setText(df.format(row1_value));
            }

            //calculate second row
            if (!edit4.getText().toString().equals("") && !edit5.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                double num4 = Double.parseDouble((edit4.getText().toString()));
                double num5 = Double.parseDouble((edit5.getText().toString()));

                row2_value = num4 * num5;

                double num6 = 0;
                if (!edit6.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    num6 = Double.parseDouble((edit6.getText().toString()));
                    row2_value = (((100 - num6) * num5) * num4) / 100;
                }

                textViewSub2.setText(df.format(row2_value));
            }


            /* ========================================================================== */
            //calculate the NBT
            double numNbt = 0;
            if (!editNbt.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                numNbt = Double.parseDouble(editNbt.getText().toString());
                row_nbt_value =  numNbt / 100;

                if (row1_value !=0){
                       row1_value_new =  row1_value * row_nbt_value;
                }
                nbtText.setText(df.format(row1_value_new));
            }

            return df.format(row1_value_new + row2_value);
        }
    }
```

This is my LogCat:

> 09-12 09:55:51.908 1624-1624/? I/InstallerConnection: connecting...
>   09-12 09:55:51.936 1624-1624/? I/InstallerConnection: disconnecting...
>   09-12 09:55:51.978 1624-1624/system_process I/InstallerConnection: connecting...
>   09-12 09:56:04.447 2433-2502/com.google.android.gms I/FA-SVC: App measurement is starting up, version: 11055
>   09-12 09:56:04.530 2433-2922/com.google.android.gms I/FA-SVC: This instance being marked as an uploader
>   09-12 09:56:04.794 2433-2441/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/networkstatistics.sqlite' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
>   09-12 09:56:14.889 2433-2441/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db.16' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
>   09-12 09:56:14.890 2433-2441/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db.18' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
>   09-12 09:56:14.892 2433-2441/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

Comment: calculate in same method lashCalculate();

Comment: @J Ramesh, Yes I calculate in the same method, but does not work, Can you give me a suggestion please

Comment: Can you please xml?

Comment: Also can you please mention which edittext is edited like editext1 editext2 etc. looks like you dont need to add a textwatcher to all the edittexts and especially not to the textview

Comment: @ MadScientist, User can add optional Value to editNbt edittext field

Comment: @J Ramesh, how to add another code

Comment: try given answer

Comment: add this in your code  editNbt.addTextChangedListener(new LashCustomTextWatcher());

Comment: remove this line textViewResult.addTextChangedListener(new LashCustomTextWatcher());   TextWatcher is useful for EditText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add this line in your code [updated]

    editNbt.addTextChangedListener(new LashCustomTextWatcher()); 


change this code in lashCalculate() method
//calculate the NBT


 double numNbt = 0;
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(editNbt.getText().toString())) {
        numNbt = Double.parseDouble(editNbt.getText().toString());
        row_nbt_value = numNbt / 100;

        if (row1_value != 0) {
            row1_value_new = row1_value * row_nbt_value;
        }
        nbtText.setText(df.format(row1_value_new));
    } else {
        row1_value_new = row1_value;
    }

    return df.format(row1_value_new + row2_value);
```

Comment: @J Ramesh, I add this line, But as before still my app crashing and not working

Comment: can you please crash log?

Comment: Your xml not contains textViewNbt12 and Edittext11

Comment: I think you are getting NullPointerException right?

Comment: @J Ramesh,I add textViewNbt12 and Edittext11, But error is there

Comment: @J Ramesh,Now error is not ther and It works, But It doesnot update the Final Result Field as I want, I think I have some problem with the code, Please if you could help me

Answer (score 0):

This is the XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <!--<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
            android:ems="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Col 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
            android:ems="3"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText5" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText3"
            android:ems="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Col 2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_result"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
            android:text="Final Result"
            android:textColor="#232123"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextViewsub2"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/TextViewsub2"
            android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
            android:ems="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Col 3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextViewsub1"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/TextViewsub1"
            android:ems="4"
            android:hint=""
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText3"
            android:ems="4"
            android:text="Sub Total"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextViewsub1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:ems="3"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="Sub 1"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
            android:ems="2"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="First Row"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:ems="3"
            android:text="Second Row"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="3"
            android:hint=""
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText6" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
            android:ems="3"
            android:hint=""
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextViewsub2"
            android:ems="3"
            android:hint=""
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextViewsub2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/TextViewsub1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextViewsub1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextViewsub1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/TextViewsub1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText7"
            android:ems="3"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="Sub 2"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="next Page"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView_result"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView_result" />












        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Total Value"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView_result"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_result"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText7" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            android:text="Add Value (Optional)"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText7"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="%"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextViewsub2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/TextViewsub2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editText13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Sub value"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText9" />


    </RelativeLayout>

        <!--</RelativeLayout>-->
```

Comment: @J Ramesh, I've just seen your comment, I'll try and inform you. Thank you as you're trying to help me

Comment: @J Ramesh, it works perfectly, Thank you very much, If I add another field like this, does it work in the same way?? Could you please explain the thing you have done to the code , if can